# Evaluate coordinate of turning point : $y={1-\sin x\over 1+\cos x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, derivatives

How do I find the coordinate of the turning of $(1)$
$$y={1-\sin x\over 1+\cos x}={u\over v}\tag1$$

Using the Quotient rule:
$${dy\over dx}={vu^{'}-v^{'}u\over v^2}$$
$u=1-\sin x$, $u^{'}=-\cos x$

$v=1+\cos x$, $v^{'}=-\sin x$

$${dy\over dx}={-\cos x(1+\cos x)+(1-\sin x)\sin x\over (1+\cos x)^2}$$
$$={-1-\cos x+\sin x\over (1+\cos x)^2}$$

Turning point happens ${dy\over dx}=0$.

$$1+\cos x=\sin x\tag2$$

How do I solve for $x$?

@King tut: 
$$\sqrt{2}\sin(x-{\pi\over 4})=1$$

$$x={\pi\over 2}$$

$$y={1-\pi\over 1+\pi}$$

Turning point $({\pi\over 2},{1-\pi\over 1+\pi})$

Comment: You must compute the second derivative to get a turning point ( if it exists)

Comment: May write as $\sin(x)-\cos(x) = 1 $ or $\sqrt{2}\sin(x-\pi/4) = 1$ ..

Comment: btw what is turning point, its confusing term for me...

Comment: @KingTut a turning point is a maximum or minimum point

Comment: you mean $x=\frac{\pi}{2}\implies y=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Hint*** for the trigonometric equation

$$1+\cos x=\sin x$$
$$\cos(0)+\cos x=\sin x$$
$$2\cos(x/2)\cos(x/2)=\sin x$$
$$2\cos^2(x/2)=\sin x$$
$$2\cos^2(x/2)=2\sin(x/2)\cos(x/2)$$
$$\cos(x/2)(\cos(x/2)-\sin(x/2))=0$$
$$ \implies 
\begin{cases}
\cos(x/2)=0 \\
\cos(x/2)=\sin(x/2)
\end{cases}
$$
$$....$$

Answer (score 0):

$y={1-\sin x\over 1+\cos x} = \frac{1}{1+\cos{x}}-\frac{\sin{x}}{1+\cos{x}} = \frac{1}{2} \left(1+\tan^2{\frac{x}{2}} \right) - \tan{\frac{x}{2}}$

$y' = \frac{1}{2}\tan{\frac{x}{2}}(1+\tan^2{\frac{x}{2}}) - \frac{1}{2}(1+\tan^2{\frac{x}{2}}) \stackrel{!}{=} 0 \Rightarrow \tan{\frac{x}{2}} = 1 \rightarrow x_t = \frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi \; k \in \mathbb{Z}$

$y''(x) = \left( \frac{1}{2}(1+\tan^2{\frac{x}{2}})(\tan{\frac{x}{2}}-1) \right)' = \frac{1}{2}(\ldots)(\tan{\frac{x}{2}}-1) + \frac{1}{2}(1+\tan^2{\frac{x}{2}})\frac{1}{2}(1+\tan^2{\frac{x}{2}})$

$\Rightarrow y''(x_t) \gt 0$